# Moment.js diff is returning zero even when there is a difference

Tags: javascript, date, ecmascript-6, momentjs

I'm trying to get the difference between two date objects in minutes. The problem is when the date objects are same, it returns zero. But when the difference becomes 1 also the diff returns zero.

My code goes as below

```
let currentDate = Moment();
let takenDateString = `${currentDateString(date)} ${hours}:${minutes} ${isAM ? 'AM' : 'PM'}`
let takenDate = Moment(takenDateString, 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm A');

console.log("=======================")
console.log(currentDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm A'))
console.log(takenDateString);
console.log(takenDate.diff(currentDate, "minutes"));
console.log("=======================")
```

Also this is what being printed in the log

```
Util.js:62 =======================
Util.js:63 2019-09-04 03:26 PM
Util.js:64 2019-09-04 03:26 PM
Util.js:65 0
Util.js:66 =======================
Util.js:62 =======================
Util.js:63 2019-09-04 03:26 PM
Util.js:64 2019-09-04 03:26 PM
Util.js:65 0
Util.js:66 =======================
Util.js:62 =======================
Util.js:63 2019-09-04 03:26 PM
Util.js:64 2019-09-04 03:27 PM
Util.js:65 0
Util.js:66 =======================
Util.js:62 =======================
Util.js:63 2019-09-04 03:26 PM
Util.js:64 2019-09-04 03:28 PM
Util.js:65 1
Util.js:66 =======================
```

You an see the behaviour above. Even when the time difference is 1 it returns zero and when it 2 it returns 1. Why this odd behaviour?

Comment: Can you try: `takenDate.diff(currentDate, "minutes", true)` this will return a float instead of an integer.

Comment: Could it be that it takes the difference in seconds and anything less than 60 seconds is counted as 0 minutes?

Comment: The answer depends on expected result. Does `2019-09-04 03:27:00.001 - 2019-09-04 03:26:59.999` count as having a difference of one minute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/moment/moment/blob/2e2a5b35439665d4b0200143d808a7c26d6cd30f/src/lib/moment/diff.js) of the diff function in Moment we see that it takes the absolute value of the difference in minutes and floors it. So for example 0.5 minutes becomes 0, 1.9 minutes becomes 1.

Passing the third parameter as `true` to `diff()` will give you an answer as a floating point number (which can be negative).

```
let a = moment("2019-09-04T09:33:30.000");
let b = moment("2019-09-04T09:34:00.000");
a.diff(b, "minutes") // -> 0
a.diff(b, "minutes", true) // -> -0.5
```

If you want the difference in "minutes on the clock" you can use `minutes()`

```
let a = moment("2019-09-04T09:33:30.000");
let b = moment("2019-09-04T09:34:00.000");
b.minutes() - a.minutes() // -> 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Moment truncates (i.e. rounds down) the diff (so 59 seconds will become 0 minutes).

https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/

Answer (score 0):

I think we need to let moment know which formats our dates are

```
// My code when the result is 0 even tho it's not supposed to
// I thought x and y were supposed to have the same format so I did this
const x = moment('2020-12-28T17:00:00.000Z', "DD/MM/YYYY"); 
const y = moment('30/04/2023');
const diff = y.diff(x, "years", true);  // diff = 0;

// While actually we should just clarify our dates' formats
// Below is the working version
const x = moment('2020-12-28T17:00:00.000Z', "YYYY-MM-DD");
const y = moment('30/04/2023', "DD/MM/YYYY");
const diff = moment(y).diff(x, "years", true);  // diff = 2.338888888888889;
```

Answer (score -1):

You are supposed to convert takenDateString to a date object before passing it to moment.

EDIT: You can also use strings, but converting to a date object worked for me.

```
let currentDate = Moment();
let takenDateString = `${currentDateString(date)} ${hours}:${minutes} ${isAM ? 'AM' : 'PM'}`
let takenDate = Moment(new Date(takenDateString), 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm A'); // pass a date object instead

console.log("=======================")
console.log(currentDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm A'))
console.log(takenDateString);
console.log(takenDate.diff(currentDate, "minutes"));
console.log("=======================")
```

Comment: It is not necessary to convert it to a date. Moment.js can use strings aswell: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/

Comment: @LuudvanKeulen Sure, but why the downvote? I tried this solution and it works. Did you try it out?

Comment: They both work fine. Doesn't matter if it's a string or a date.